# Sweater doesn't move with neck

Tags: rigging

I'm working on a 3D Avatar, and have combined some of my Models. I've noticed that the neck part of the Sweater doesn't move with the rest of the body, atleast not how it should. But the arms do, the sweater is one part by the way.

My Question is, how can i fix that, I've tried it with Data Transfer but that messes everything up.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is it possible that the vertex groups for your sweater have some missing vertex weights near the neck region? What do you see when you select the sweater in Object Mode, then switch to Weight Paint Mode, then select the vertex groups near the neck region? Do any colors show up other than blue? If not, you will need to recreate those missing vertex weight values.

Comment: I've added an image, the hole Sweater is dark blue/black and the arms work it's just the neck that doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for adding a picture but it doesn't show what I'm asking about. When I asked about blue color, I was expecting a shot of rainbow colors, with red, orange, yellow, green and blue, signifying the relative level of influence of the vertex weights in your neck region. What do you see when you select your mesh in Object Mode and then go to Weight Paint Mode and then Shift-Right Click on the neck area? What colors appear? If only blue appears, you have no vertex weights in the neck region, and that is the problem in that case. You would need to add them.

Comment: Thanks for the Help, as u see in the updated question, I've added some "good" amount of wheight to the sweater and now it stays in place with the neck. I don't know why there aren't any other wheight tho. But the problem is solved for me ;)

Comment: Ah, yes. I see the new picture now. Glad you got it sorted.